# How to make this bash prime generator faster [SPOJ]

Tags: bash, performance, generator, primes

I'm doing the SPOJ challenge named Prime Generator, however in BASH, the judge says

> time limit
>   exceeded

The code gives requested results, and this algorythm was accepted in C++ and Java

```
#!/bin/bash

read ITERATIONS

for (( i=0; i<$ITERATIONS; i++ ))
do
        read START END

        for (( j=$START; j<=$END; j++ ))
        do
                isPrime=1

                if [ $j -eq 1 ]
                then
                        isPrime=0
                fi

                for (( k=2; k*k<=$j; k++ ))
                do
                        if (($j % $k == 0))
                        then
                                isPrime=0
                                break
                        fi
                done

                if [ $isPrime -eq 1 ]
                then
                        echo "$j"
                fi
        done
done
```

My question is, how can I speed this code up? Did I do something silly that slows it down?

Comment: Have a look at the [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primality_test) that also uses a loop but with increments of 6 instead of 1

Comment: Alternate implementation on [rosettacode.org](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Primality_by_trial_division#UNIX_Shell)

Comment: enumerate and test only the odd numbers in your range START...END and test them by primes from 3 up to the sqrt of END, which you will need to find separately, beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is using bc an option?

```
read -r ITERATIONS
for ((i = $ITERATIONS; i; --i)); do
        read -r START END
        ((START = START == 1 ? 2 : START))
        echo '
for (j='"$START"'; j<='"$END"'; ++j) {
        isprime=1
        for (k=2; k*k<=j; ++k) {
                if (j%k == 0) {
                        isprime=0
                        break
                }
        }
        if (isprime == 1) {
                j
        }
}
        ' | bc
done
```

Or maybe add some concurrency, but we need to synchronize output then:

```
tmps=()
read -r ITERATIONS
for ((i = $ITERATIONS; i; --i)); do
        read -r START END
        ((START = START == 1 ? 2 : START))
        tmp=$(mktemp)
        tmps+=($tmp)
        (
        echo '
for (j='"$START"'; j<='"$END"'; ++j) {
        isprime=1
        for (k=2; k*k<=j; ++k) {
                if (j%k == 0) {
                        isprime=0
                        break
                }
        }
        if (isprime == 1) {
                j
        }
}
        ' | bc
        ) > "$tmp" &
done
wait
cat "${tmps[@]}"
rm "${tmps[@]}"
```